Why does the Archimedes Principle fail to explain the "bottom case" / "side case"?
I was scrolling through Wikipedia and came across an exception to the Archimedes Principle, however I was unable to understand what they meant.
They've mentioned that Archimedes Principle does not apply when the side of the vessel is touching thee bottom of the container provided that there is no seepage of fluid.
This was what I saw on wiki

